# Unwrapping elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to un-wrap (or un-nest) some elements that are currently wrapped in paragraph tags (like `<p>` tags). But they should not be, and I need to be able to correct this using XSLT.

It could look like this, e.g:

```
<paragraph>Some text here with a <bold>word</bold> in bold, for example, and then an image:
    <image href="whatever.png"></image>
    and possibly some more text here.
</paragraph>
```

Here I need to separate out the text (including the inline bold tag) as one paragraph, followed by the image separately, not inside the paragraph, and then followed by a new paragraph for the text at the end. Like this:

```
<paragraph>Some text here with a <bold>word</bold> in bold, for example, and then an image:</paragraph>
    <image href="whatever.png"></image>
<paragraph>and possibly some more text here.</paragraph>
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this. I can do it for each node, but then the bold tag will also be placed in a separate paragraph, and I don't want that.

Please note that the  tag is just an example. The same situation will occur with lists, tables, etc. And basically the problem is that they have been wrapped in paragraph tags when they shouldn't have. So the text (including inline elements such as bold, italics etc) need to be preserved as paragraphs in one chunk, but the other types of elements, images, tables and so on need to be un-wrapped from it, still preserving the right order of the content of course.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Are the `image`, `list`, `table` elements always direct children of the `paragraph` elements? Or can there be further nesting like `<paragraph>This some <bold>bold <image href="foo.png"/></bold> text.</paragraph>`? Which version of XSLT do you use or can you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::image | self::table | self::list)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy select="..">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with XSLT 2.0 you could change the template for `paragraph` to

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::image | self::table | self::list)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <paragraph>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </paragraph>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0 the following is an example using sibling-recursion to try to solve that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph/image | paragraph/table | paragraph/list">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph/node()[not(self::image | self::table | self::list)]">
  <paragraph>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::image | self::table | self::list)]" mode="copy"/>
  </paragraph>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[self::image | self::table | self::list][1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph/node()[not(self::image | self::table | self::list)]" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::image | self::table | self::list)]" mode="copy"/>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! It works when testing with XSLT 2.0 and Saxon. Only problem is I very probably will have to use XSLT 1.0 in this case, I forgot to say that. Any chance there is an equivalent for 1.0?

Comment: @AndersSvensson, I have added an XSLT 1.0 sample doing sibling recursion (it starts with `paragraph/node()[1]` and then walks the following-sibling axis to collect the nodes belonging together and to directly output `image`, `table` and `list` elements).